# How to do more than one square and to align them in rows and columns

Tags: android-studio

I have the following square shape and have managed to align it by using the marginBottom and marginLeft etc but how would I create more than one of the same shape? I tried something like this but only one is showing at the moment....

This is the code for my box shape:

```
 <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
           <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
           <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
       </shape>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
           <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
           <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>

This is my main activity code:

<TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/box"
        android:text="Write here"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box"
    android:text="Write here"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="172dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Write here"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.824" />
```

You can get multiple boxes like what you have by duplicating it just assign them and put them into position.